# Formatting strings with placeholders in SQL Server like in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to store generic messages in an SQL Server table, and then get the values and use them within a stored procedure, e.g. "Dear John", where instead of "John" I would like to be able to insert any name obtained within the procedure. In C#, if I stored the text like this: "Dear {0}", I could then easily format it: string.Format(myString, name). Can I do anything like this in SQL Server, other than just REPLACE? I heard something like using CLR in SQL Server, but have no idea whether or how it would work. What is the best way to achieve what I need?

Could you please help?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[xp_sprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175014.aspx) may be what you're looking for :

```
DECLARE @ret_string varchar (255)
EXEC Master.DBO.xp_sprintf @ret_string OUTPUT, '(%s, %s)', 'Hello', 'World'
PRINT @ret_string
```

Outputs `(Hello, World)`